# .NET 5 WEB API - Can't configure CORS with subdomain (or even with the full domain name)

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm having a problem with configuring CORS in our web API project.

in Startup.cs we have the following configuration:

```
protected override void ConfigureApplication(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
{
     base.ConfigureApplication(app, env, appLifetime);
     app.UseCors();

     // .... 
}

public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // ...
   this.ConfigureCrossOrigin(services);
   // ...
}
       

private void ConfigureCrossOrigin(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string[] allowedOrigin = new string[]
    {
        "https://dev-XX.myapp.nl/",
        "https://*.myapp.nl/"
    };

    services.AddCors(options =>
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            builder
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                .WithOrigins(allowedOrigin)
                .AllowCredentials()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()));
}
```

Now, we have a client website that URL is **https://dev-XX.myapp.nl/**

and our server (API) is running at **https://dev-api.myapp.nl/**

so, for example, when the client site wants to perform a login it will send a POST request to https://dev-api.myapp.nl/api/login

The problem is that no matter what variation I put in the allowedOrigins I get a CORS error
I tried:

```
"https://*.myapp.nl/" , "https://*-XX.myapp.nl/", "https://dev-XX.myapp.nl/"
```

nothing seems to work!

By the way, we have a "development" mode that allows all origins to send requests to the API
and we configure it as follows:

```
private void ConfigureCrossOrigin(IServiceCollection services)
{
    string[] allowedOrigin = new string[]
    {
        "https://dev-XX.myapp.nl/", 
        "https://*.myapp.nl/"
    };

    services.AddCors(options =>
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            builder
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials()));
}
```

This works just fine but I don't want to allow such a thing in production

So, how do I achieve using CORS with a subdomain?

edit:
I forgot to mention that since we are using http-only cookies we must configure the AllowCredentials function

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

having a look into the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is telling me, that you're doing everything quite straight ahead.

I'm wondering about the base class of your startup and what it's about.
Be aware the Cors need to be added to the app before endpoint mapping